# matplotlib says libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, python

I am trying to install matplotlib version 2.0.0. I don't have root access, hence can't use sudo/apt-get
When I tried installing matplotlib, it showed dependencies on freetype and libpng. So, I executed the following steps:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.34.tar.gz
tar -xzf libpng-1.6.34.tar.gz 
cd libpng-1.6.34/
./configure --prefix=/home/$username$/
make
make check
make install

cd ..
wget http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.5.3.tar.gz
tar xzf freetype-2.5.3.tar.gz
cd freetype-2.5.3
./configure --prefix=/home/$username$ --without-png
make && make install
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/$username$/lib/pkgconfig

pip install matplotlib==2.0.0
```

Which worked perfectly fine. But when I do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`  it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you add the directory containing that library to the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: @ubfan1 I tried this: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/$username$/lib/libpng16.so.16
Still showed me the same error.

Comment: Stop the path at .../lib , don't include the actual library name (there may be others needed).

Comment: This works! Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs installed in a user's home directory may also install some necessary libraries.  The way to tell the program loader where these libraries are is through the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/$HOME/<any other optional program directories>/lib"
```

This line may be added to the hidden file .profile in the home directory to set this up for each login.

If you have more than one such lib path, add a colon after the first, then add the next one.